# Behaviour : Unknown Word

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, behavior

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hapL1.png)

Anything I can do to solve this?

Comment: Restart VSCode?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is caused by your [Code Spell Checker](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker) extension. It says `Behaviour` is "incorrectly" spelled because you used a British spelling instead of the American spelling of `Behavior` (without the letter "u").

The solution is to add the word `Behaviour` to the dictionary:

1. Place your mouse caret on top of `Behaviour`. Click on the light bulb button.

   [image: Code actions button]
2. Select the option 'Add: "Behaviour" to user settings':

   [image: Add to dictionary]